# Putting map marker in non map activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dictionary

I'm new android developer and i'm trying to develop application follows the user movement in particular location with rounded path and count how much rounds he did. I want to do this in an `Activity` not in a `MapActivity`

any ideas?

**Update:**

http://s23.postimg.org/5230j4tnf/image.png

this what i'm trying to do 
i want the small dot track the user movement in circular path that he should walk around then count the rounded he did

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the LocationManager and get the fine location, and then use that latitude and longatude to manually figure out where that maps to on your circle based on the lat and long of the edges of the path on google maps, and plot an image view of a map pointer there. This is a very round about way of doing it, but in theory it could work.